# How to create topic kafka quarkus?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

Using Spring to create a topic, it is enough to create such a bean.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableKafka
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
public class KafkaConfig {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public NewTopic requestTopic() {
        Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put("retention.ms", kafkaProperties.getStartReport().getRequestReplyTimeOut().toString());
        return new NewTopic(kafkaProperties.getStartReport().getTopicName(), kafkaProperties.getStartReport().getTopicPartitions(), kafkaProperties.getStartReport().getReplicationFactor()).configs(configs);
    }
```

How can I create a topic with the required number of partitions and replication factor from the Quarkus code?

```
@Slf4j
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "kafka.bootstrap.servers")
    String kafkaHost;

    @Inject
    KafkaOutgoingProperties kafkaOutgoingProperties;


    @Produces
    public NewTopic requestTopic() {
        Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        return new NewTopic(kafkaOutgoingProperties.finishReportChannel().topic(),
                kafkaOutgoingProperties.finishReportChannel().partitions(),
                kafkaOutgoingProperties.finishReportChannel().replicationFactor()).configs(configs);
    }
    
}
```

I tried to create the same in quarkus but it doesn't work.

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work". You shouldn't be able to import NewTopic from Spring in Quarkus

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the easiest solution but you can create an [`AdminClient`](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#kafka-bare-clients) by yourself

```java
@Produces
AdminClient getAdmin() {
  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
  ...
  return KafkaAdminClient.create(props);
}
```

and use [`AdminClient.createTopics`](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#createTopics(java.util.Collection)) method to create your topics programatically